# How to compare two dataframes' structures

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes and I want to compare their structures only.
I tried to do this:

```
df0Info = df0.info()
df1Info = df1.info()
if df0Info == df1Info:
    print("They are same")
else:
    print("They are diff")
```

I found the result always is same whether the two dataframes structures are same or different. How can I get the correct result?

Comment: What about the structures do you want to be the same? Their column names? Their shape? Their values?

Comment: What is your definition of structure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.info` prints a summary of a DataFrame and returns `None`, so comparing outputs to one another will always be True because you're essentially testing `None == None`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `df.info` returns `None`, you can create the data required and compare those:

```
df0Info = pd.concat([df0.dtypes, df0.count()], axis=1)
df1Info = pd.concat([df1.dtypes, df1.count()], axis=1)
if df0Info.eq(df1Info).all().all():
    print("Same")
else:
    print("Different")
```

Comment: pd.concat([df0.dtypes], axis=1) is enough. df0.count are different because data of two frames are different

Comment: Then you don't need `concat` at all. Just `df0Info = df0.dtypes`. I just reproduced the data contained in `info`, like you mentioned in your question.